# unscheduling job in quartz

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz to schedule job in my c# .net application. I am storing all data in database. My code is :

```
ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
        _scheduler = schedFact.GetScheduler();
        _scheduler.Start();

       job = JobBuilder.Create<JobTask>()
             .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
        .Build();

          trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
            .WithSchedule(
        CronScheduleBuilder.CronSchedule("0 0/5 * * * ?"))
         .Build();
         _scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Now I would like to give user function so user can disable(unschedule) job. I have look in quartz tutorial but I can't find the way to do it in c#.

Answer (score 2):

You can call following method in **IScheduler**

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Remove the indicated Quartz.Trigger from the scheduler.
    bool UnscheduleJob(string triggerName, string groupName);
```

Comment: I can only see this method  UnscheduleJob(Quartz.TriggerKey key) and I am not sure how to get the trigger key.

Comment: you can "new" a TriggerKey by the triggerName, and triggerGroupName, in your case "trigger1" and "group1"

Answer (score 1):

Your Job class can implement `IInterruptableJob` interface and implement

```
public void Interrupt()
{
    JobKey jobKey = new JobKey(JobName, MyService.GroupName);
    Scheduler.Interrupt(jobKey);
}
```